# Missing LocalHistory in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2 ( Community Edition)

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2 ( Community Edition) and not able to find any local history. Also, I am trying to set the days for Local History but not able to find the localhistory parameter in Help->Find Actions->Registry

Any guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local history should be available in the `File | Local History` menu, or in the right-click menu in the editor. The `Duration of storing changes in Local History` setting can now be found in `Settings | Advanced Settings | IDE`